# how to make css curve box with gradient & shadow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the css curve box with gradient and shadow as well as.
so how i can make with pure css and it should be only in one div not much code.

For reference see the attached image:-

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything you've tried so far? Will there be content within this box or is it for decoration only?

Comment: no didn't make it i am trying to find out how i can this box with pure css...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just make is border-radius as like this

**Css**

```
div {
width:200px;
margin:auto;
margin-top:20px;
height:200px;
background:red;
border-radius:25px;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(68,68,68,0.8);;
position:relative;
}

div:beforae {
content:"";
position:absolute;
border-left:15px solid blue; 
border-right:15px solid green;
height:200px; 
border-radius:15px 0 0 15px;   
}
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div></div>​
```

and now check to live demo  http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Vsvg2/74/